# For the standard normal distribution N(0,1) , find the median, quartiles and interquartile range

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

> For the standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$, find the median,
>   quartiles and interquartile range. (Give all answers to two decimal
>   places.)

I know the mean is $0$, which means the median is $0$ and that the standard deviation is $1$, but how do I find the quartiles? I know that the interquartile range is $Q_3-Q_1$.

How would I begin solving a problem like this?

Answer (score 3):

Look at a [table](https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~lzhou/stat302/standardnormaltable.pdf) of the standard normal distribution.

At what values of z it is $\Phi(z)=0.25, \Phi(z)=0.50$ or $\Phi(z)=0.75$ ?

The values of z are the quartiles $Q_1,Q_2$ and $Q_3$.

Comment: I don't see numbers higher than 0.50. What does that mean?

Comment: and what does phi represent?

Comment: First question: Second page. Second question: $\Phi(z)$ is the cdf (cummulative density function) of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: I got .68 for Q1 but apparently that's wrong? I used the following formula: z = (x - mean)/(standard deviation)

Comment: actually I just used the table to get .68 and that didn't work. .67 didn't work either.

Comment: It is $\Phi(-0.67)\approx 0.25$. Pay attention to the minus sign. Therefore $Q_1=-0.67$

Comment: I get it now! Thank you!

Comment: @James You´re welcome.